# Angular 6: chartjs value not updating with dynamic value update

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular6, angular-chart

I'm using `Angular 6`.

In my **component.ts** file, I have to initialize graph and doing so in **ngOnIt()** method like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-detail',
  templateUrl: './contact-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-detail.component.css']
})
export class ContactDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  contact_id: string;
  public graph_data_year;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private graphDataService: GraphDataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      param => {
        this.contact_id = param['id'];
      }
    );


    /**
     * Get Amount Given Graph Data
     */
    this.graphDataService.get_data(this.contact_id).subscribe(
      res => {
        const data = [];
        res.forEach(e => {
          data.push(e.total);
        });
        this.graph_data_year = data;
        this._setGraphData();
      }
    );

    this.initializeGraph();
  }

  _setGraphData() {
    this.lineBigDashboardChartData[0]['data'] = this.graph_data_year;

    // this console here gives updated value in the console window, but no update on chart
    console.log(this.lineBigDashboardChartData);
  }

  /**
   * Graph
   */
  initializeGraph() {
    ...

    this.lineBigDashboardChartData = [
      {
        label: 'Data',
        ...
        ...
        data: this.graph_data_year
      }
    ];
    this.lineBigDashboardChartLabels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];

    this.lineBigDashboardChartType = 'line';
  }

}
```

and **component.html** is like

```
<canvas baseChart id="bigDashboardChart"
   [datasets]="lineBigDashboardChartData"
   [labels]="lineBigDashboardChartLabels"
   [chartType]="lineBigDashboardChartType"></canvas>
```

But it does not update the chart with the updated value of **graph_data_year** which is updated by **this.graphDataService**. and shows the blank chart.

`console.log(this.lineBigDashboardChartData);` after updating data prints updated values in console window but chart data is not update.

How can I have an async variable inside component which on the update, updates value in every place it has been used in the component? Or how can I refresh the cart after updating the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended @Mehmet answer and this fixed my issue.

```
this.lineBigDashboardChartLabels.length = 0;
this.lineBigDashboardChartLabels.push(...label_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding ChartType like this ; `[chartType]="'line'"`
And you should not change labels original array reference.
Try this one for creating dynamic labels;

```
this.lineBigDashboardChartLabels.length = 0;
this.lineBigDashboardChartLabels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you move `this.initializeGraph()` to just below the console.log statement you have inside of ngOnInit

```
this.graphDataService.get_data(this.contact_id).subscribe(
  res => {
    const data = [];
    res.forEach(e => {
      data.push(e.total);
    });
    this.graph_data_year = data;
    console.log(this.graph_data_year);
    this.initializeGraph();
  }
);
```

Comment: I had tried that too but graph data is not refreshing once it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is loading the chart first before the data is initialized.
Add an *ngIf (data has a value) to the parent div.

This ensures the data is updated before chart is loaded.